# cordinates to placename using google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

im new to google maps, i used html5 to get user's cordinates of latitude and longitude but i wanted to get the nearest place name of the user so that he may select that,(why type if we can click?) i googled and googled but cant do any thing. i have written these scripts today....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your position:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true">
//only a v3 api library
</script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>


var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)

  mapholder=document.getElementById('mapholder')
  mapholder.style.height='250px';
  mapholder.style.width='500px';

  var myOptions={
  center:latlon,zoom:18,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl:false,
  navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"Some where here"});

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({latLng:latlon},function(results, status) {

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
              infoWindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
              infoWindow.open(map);
            }
          }
        });
  }
function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
      break;
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have done all these so far, now what i need to do is that, i want to get the place name for the location given by those two variables:`lat,lon`so that i can find the place name, can any one help me out?
i have found this link which may be helpful but i cant figure it out,,, i dont need the placeinfo in the map, but i want to get place name in a variable

thanks in advanced.. In case question is not clear, please mention me, and ill try to be more clear,,,, i apologize for my language....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already get all what you need, a geocoding-result. (**results** inside the **geocode()**-callback)

Those results(an array) consist of different items, one of them should have a member **types**(also an array) where the 2nd item is set to "**locality**" , this usually marks the item as a city. When you found this item, the long_name - member of the item will give you the city-name.

More info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=en#GeocodingAddressTypes

A note related to the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true">
//only a v3 api library
</script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

you're loading the maps-API twice, because the first `<script/>` will load the maps-API **and** the places-library. You better remove the 2nd `<script/>`

Comment: thanks for the script double issue and i am sorry because i could get you.. when i alerted the result variable, it showed only the object... i mean how will i get the text from it? please help me. im new to javascript to... but again thanks that i didnt knew about the result contained exactly i wanted for... now looking forward for converting that object into array

Comment: i tried this:

`alert(results.formatted_address)//says undefined`
and others these too
`alert(results[0])//it says object
alert(results.street_address)//it says undefined
alert(results.locality)//it also says undefined`
but nothing happened every time it alerted an object

Comment: i used json to convert object to text but couldnot find any property or may be i am missing something. i did this:

`alert(JSON.stringify(results))`
but i cant do any thing please help